# Cannot access a disposed object Asp.net Identity Core UserManager Deleting a user

Tags: .net, entity-framework, blazor-server-side

Trying to fetch a user using their id and deleting their record using `UserManager`

```
private async Task deleteUser(string userId)
    {

        try
        {
            IdentityUser? user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);


            using (var transaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
            {
                if (user is not null)
                {
                    IList<string> roles = await UserManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
                    IdentityResult roleResult = await UserManager.RemoveFromRolesAsync(user, roles);

                    if (roleResult.Succeeded)
                    {
                        IdentityResult identityResult = await UserManager.DeleteAsync(user);

                        if (roleResult.Succeeded)
                        {
                            Snackbar.Add("Sucess", Severity.Success);
                            transaction.Commit(); //only commit if user and all his logins/roles have been deleted
                        }
                    }

                    return;
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.LogError(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

The error is thrown when GetRolesAsync is called.

Comment: What is the call stack for the exception? How is your UserManager reference declared/injected?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by creating a scope and injecting the `UserManager` in my method instead of on the blazor page level.

```
 using var scope = ServiceProvider.CreateScope();
 userManager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<IdentityUser>>();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).